# Anaconda navigator requires me to install the applications again and again but shows error while installing

Tags: python, linux, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter-lab

The base environment started to show that it requires the applications like notebook and jupyterlab to be installed when it was already installed.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxkiA.png)

I tried to install them but it shows that multiple errors occured. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1oR1.png)

This is the commands from terminal when launching anaconda:

```
    ((base) ubuntu@ubuntu-Aspire-A515-56:~$ anaconda-navigator
    2023-08-25 13:04:32,092 - WARNING linux_scaling.get_scaling_factor_using_dbus:44
    Can't detect system scaling factor settings for primary monitor.

  Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
  libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris: /usr/lib/dri/iris_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
  libGL error: failed to load driver: iris
  libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
  libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
  <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>
  <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>
  <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>
  <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>
  <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>
  <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>
  <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>
  2023-08-25 13:18:01,373 - ERROR __init__._conda_output_ready:1059
  Multiple Errors Encountered.
```